# Make a varchar(50) column unique

Tags: sql-server, unique, varchar

I have a column (which represents an e-mail) in a SQL Server database with `varchar(50)` as data type and I would like to make it unique (do not allow the same two e-mail addresses). I cannot find a way to make such column unique in SQL Server Management Studio.

How to do that?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In T-SQL it would be

```
ALTER  TABLE  MyTable WITH CHECK 
   ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_MyTable_Email UNIQUE (EmailAddress)
```

Or as an explicit index

```
CREATE  UNIQUE INDEX IXU_Email ON MyTable (EmailAddress)
```

Edit: I can't see how to create a constraint in the SSMS GUI: other answers show how to manage indexes. I do only use SQL though, never the GUI for this kind of work

Comment: When I create index using T-SQL where I can find this index in SQL Server management studio?

Comment: In object explorer, find your table. F5 to refresh, you'll see it there.

Comment: Then expand your table and look in the folder called "Indexes".

Comment: @gbn What index type should i use, clustered or non-clustered for e-mail field?

Comment: @Tomas: I'd assume non-clustered because you already have a primary key. This will *default* to being clustered and you can have only one clustered index. (note that "primary key" and "clustered/non-clustered" are different ideas when you dig deeper but out of scope here)

Comment: To do this in SSMS right click on the table name and select "design" from the context menu.  Right click on the design window that opens up  and select Indexes Keys.  In the dialog that opens up click the "Add" button.  Highlight the new Index, change is name in the properties if desired; change the "Is Unique" property to yes, and change type "Unique Key" Click the ellipses in the Columns property and in the popup use the drop down to select the column you want to be unique. close the indexes/keys window and save the design window.  voila

Comment: How do I add unique field only for some user. Let's say I have userID=2 and for that userID is only allowed unique phone number. Two different userID's can have the same phone?

Comment: i receive this error :"Column 'email' in table 'table1' is of a type that is invalid for use as a key column in an index". column type is varchar(50)

Answer (score 7):

In the `Object Explorer` under the table right-click the `Indexes` folder and choose `New Index...`.

In the window that appears enter `Index name:`, tick the `Unique` checkbox and add your email field from the `Add...` button then click OK.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TableName] ADD CONSTRAINT UNQ__TableName__ColumnName UNIQUE ([ColumnName])
```

From this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191166.aspx